# SQL - Loop + UPDATE in tables

Tags: mysql, sql

With a POST METHOD `$tab_tuto_sauvegarde = $_POST['tableau_valeurs_modifiees'];` a Ajax request returns to me this informations :

```
 [Chapitres] => Array
            [0] => Array
                    [titre_chapitre] => BONJOUR
                    [id_chapitre] => 1

            [2] => Array
                    [titre_chapitre] => Manger
                    [id_chapitre] => 3
```

I have a TABLE named `'Chapitres'`

```
|  Id_chapitre  ||  titre_chapitre |
__________________________________
|    1          ||    C01          |
|    2          ||    C02          |
|    3          ||    C03          |
|    4          ||    C04          |
...
```

I need to UPDATE `'titre_chapitre'` in my table `'Chapitre'` `WHERE id_chapitre = "[id_chapitre] return by ajax"` for each index results return by ajax request
(in this example index [0] and [2]... but it can be  index [0] and [1]  and [4]...)

The result must be like that

```
|  Id_chapitre  ||  titre_chapitre |
__________________________________
|    1          ||    BONJOUR      |
|    2          ||    C02          |
|    3          ||    Manger       |
|    4          ||    C04          |
...
```

I tried this but...

```
if (isset ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Chapitres'])){
    foreach($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Chapitres'] as $index => $valeur){
    mysqli_query($BDD_connect, "UPDATE Chapitres SET titre = titre_chapitre(from array ajax) WHERE Id_chapitre = id_chapitre(from array ajax) "); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use parameterized queries. You should check, if `$tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Chapitres']` is an array too. Prepare a statement before your loop. Then use `foreach(tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Chapitres'] as $row) { // execute the query with binding of the values of the current row to the parameters }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it using a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($BDD_connect, "UPDATE Chapitres SET titre = ? WHERE id_tutoriel = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $titre, $id);
foreach ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Chapitres'] as $chapitre) {
    $titre = $chapitre['titre_chapitre'];
    $id = $chapitre['id_chapitre'];
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Scuse me but I'm a big noob in PHP... how can i replace at the first line the "?" by '$titre' ans the second '?' by '$id' ? and what is the 'si' at the 2nd line ?